# numpy squeeze along an axis wont work

Tags: python, numpy

I try to use numpy squeeze to remove an axis. The shape before the squeezing is :

```
(252, 70, 1, 3, 1)
```

and my script line is :

```
var_u0 = np.squeeze(var_u0,axis=(2,))
```

but the result squeezes all the matrix :

```
var_u0.shape = (252L, 70L, 3L)
```

When i do the same in the command prompt, this thing works great.... I don't understand.

If anyone has an idea, tanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
# Random input array
A = np.random.rand(4,3,1,5,1)

# Axis to be removed
rem_axis = 2

# Squeezed output array
A_squeezed = A.reshape(np.delete(A.shape,rem_axis))
```

Here's `whos` info for confirmation -

```
In [435]: whos
Variable     Type       Data/Info
---------------------------------
A            ndarray    4x3x1x5x1: 60 elems, type `float64`, 480 bytes
A_squeezed   ndarray    4x3x5x1: 60 elems, type `float64`, 480 bytes
```

With `rem_axis = 4`, `whos` shows -

```
In [438]: whos
Variable     Type       Data/Info
---------------------------------
A            ndarray    4x3x1x5x1: 60 elems, type `float64`, 480 bytes
A_squeezed   ndarray    4x3x1x5: 60 elems, type `float64`, 480 bytes
```

To make it more robust, you can introduce one check to see whether the axis to be removed is a singleton dimension or not. So, in that case you can do -

```
# Squeezed output array
if A.shape[rem_axis]!=1:
    print('Error: Specified axis is not singleton.')
    A_squeezed = np.array([]) # Set empty as a sign of failure
         # Change it to any other signal value or keep as A itself
else:
    A_squeezed = A.reshape(np.delete(A.shape,rem_axis))
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer help me to find the issue, because it's raise me a attribute error with reshape ! In fact, my variable 'var_u0' was a netCDF4 variable. To work fine with numpy, i need to call it like an array : 'var_u0[:]', and  now it's ok !